# Number theoretic olympiad question involving a diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I don't know the exact source of this question, but here it goes:

Find all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x,y \in \Bbb{N}$ and satisfy the relation:
$$y^3=x^2+2$$

Of course $(x,y)=(5,3)$ is a solution but proving that infinitely many exist or none other exist is the part I'm stuck at.

I tried to work an infinite descent with congruent modulo but due to difference in degree one coefficient always vanishes.
I am not that good at olympiad number theory, so do help me out here.

Comment: I do not see that $(3,5)$ is a solution. Did you mean $(5,3)$?

Comment: You meant $(5,3)$, presumably.  Are you familiar with properties of algebraic integers?

Comment: No, not really. Could you point me in the direction of a resource?

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward question about the ring of integers $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-2}]$.  this ring arises because in it your expression factors as $y^3=(x-\sqrt {-2})(x+\sqrt {-2})$.  You'll want to know that this ring is a unique factorization domain, which is a fairly standard argument but not trivial if you've never seen it.  I'll dig up some good references.

Comment: After having found one solution you can write $y^3-3^3=x^2-5^2$.

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615269/how-to-prove-mathbbz-sqrt2i-ab-sqrt2i-mid-a-b-in-mathbbz-is-a) is a proof that this ring is a ufd.  [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347425/integer-solutions-for-x32-y2) contains a solution to your question.   Note, in the last reference, that the OP is asking a similar but different question.  However one of the solvers, @AndreNicolas, gives a very clear solution to your question.  Again, the argument is standard if you are used to algebraic number fields, but will take some time to read if you are not.

Comment: @A.G. I've tried that. I used congruent modulo to eliminate the integers and ended up with a bi-variable equation, which did nothing.

Comment: @lulu All the NT I've done is olympiad level so I don't have the foggiest about analytical number theory. Do you know of any resources that could help me use this tool? Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is algebraic number theory, no analytics involved.  [this link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/13282/good-algebraic-number-theory-books) contains a number of solid recommendations for introductory texts.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot!