# Number theory vs cubing

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve this diophantide equation
$$4y^3-3=k^2$$

My way was not successful
First see that $k^2$ is odd, so I assumed that $k=2n+1$.

After simplifying I got:

$$y^3=n^2+n+1$$

And I am stuck here again.
Who has a great solution?

Comment: This is an example of Mordell's equation for an elliptic curve. It has been solved ("great solution") here at this site already. Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347425/integer-solutions-for-x32-y2) and related ones (like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245299/integer-solutions-for-x2-y3-23)).

Comment: By examination of simple instances of your simplification, $y=7,\ n=18$ is one solution, yielding $k=37$. There may be others.